# Is there a way to run a function as long as an array is non zero in size?

Tags: c++, arrays, logic

Say for example my function woof() clears some array called meow[] by removing the items in it. meow[] may have items added to it by other functions, but as long as it has items in it, ie it's size is nonzero, I want woof to run and clear it.

How do I do this in C++?

Comment: Sounds like you have some Producer/Consumer action going on. Either have the Consumer periodically test the array to see if anything is in it (better, use a data structure like a `std::vector` because it's stupidly easy to test for empty) or have the Producer notify the Consumer when data is available.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do this in C++?

You would do that in c++ using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: thanks but how do I tell a vector to run some code when it is non zero in size?

Comment: @slimshady  You use the `std::vector<T:>:::size()` function for that case. Mind to provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your actual problem?